# Assigning tags to documents

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, natural-language

I am dealing with a text classification problem. Where I need to assign tags to a document. The amount of tags I need to assign varies from 1 to 5. I am struggling somewhat on how I should tackle this problem. What I tried was to encode every combination of tags with LabelEncoder() from scikit-learn, I framed it as a regression problem, because this label encoding gave me too many classes. However, since I cannot fit the entire train set in memory I can only train on a small part of the train set. The test is much bigger than the part of the train set I train my regressor on. As a result, my estimator performs really poor on the test set. In cross validation, the regressor actually gave reasonable results, this is a sign for me that framing this as a regression problem isn't the main problem. I am not sure how I should proceed. Should I frame this as a classification problem? Should I use a different encoding of my tags? Or should I simply find a way to train my classifier on more samples?

Comment: It might help to know more about the format of the data here. What is the criterion for assigning tags (semantic information, word identification, word type counts...)? How many tag categories are there in total (does 5 refer to the maximum number of joint classes here and how is it determined)? What type of regression did you try that leads to a classification of data?

Comment: There are about 30k unique tags. I have a training set with labeled tags. All the examples in the training set have tags associated with them. The amount of tags per example ranges from 1 to 5. I used the LabelEncoder to encode all the combinations of tags. For example ["java","python","excel"] might correspond to 2281. I fed these labels to a regressor and rounded the output to the nearest integer. I used a tf-idf vectorizer to model the documents. In cross_validation this gave me reasonable results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is clearly better framed as a large supervised learning problem with a great deal of hands-on assumptions. Is it possible to generate a dictionary of relevant tags, such as with a database of medical manuscripts and their corresponding MeSH terms? By calculating the frequency of such terms within each document, one can arrange those results in a large matrix. After constructing the frequency matrix, one can calculate its spectral decomposition and identify the salient terms in each document by those that have the highest orthonormal weight on the first principle component. If the matrix is rank deficient, sparse matrix methods would be a better option, such as is the case with SparCl.

Comment: Sounds, like an interesting solution.  I'll have a look into that!